# ASP:NET MVC Summary of a field as a validation for the field itself (Recursiveness)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Have the following class in a model:

```
public partial class OrganizationUnit
{
    public string code{ get; set; }
    public int OrganizationCod { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string ParentUnitCode{ get; set; }
    public int level{ get; set; }
    public string author{ get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreateDtStmp{ get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public decimal weighing { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("status")]
    public virtual Status UnitStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationUnit> OrganizationUnit1{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentUnitCode")]
    public virtual OrganizationUnit OrganizationUnit2{ get; set; }

    public OrganizationUnit ()
    {
        CreateDtStmp= DateTime.Now;
        author = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(4,HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Length - 4);
    }
}
```

Before inserting a new record I need to validate sum(weighing) can not exceed 100 including the attempted new record, considering only the records with the same ParentUnit.

Can this be done in the model or should it be done in the controller?

this is the saving controller part (basically is what is autogenerated by VS),consider that the view will send the corresponding parameter to the method:

```
private SAIM_IPM_DVContext db = new SAIM_IPM_DVContext();
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
public ActionResult Create(OrganizationUnit organizationunit)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.OrganizationUnit.Add(organizationunit);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(organizationunit);
}
```

Comment: Show us controller code for insert record operation which contains weighing validation, especially if Entity Framework is being used.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I have update the question including what @TetsuyaYamamoto refered. A little side-not this is my first MVC ASP.NET Application, so not used to this methodology and the entity framework. I do know ASP.NET.

Comment: Is `OrganizationUnit1` the collection of all other units with the same `ParentUnit`? Or do you have to fetch them from the DB?

Comment: There is a recursiveness in the table itself where ParentUnitCode is related to code. Now that collection (OrganizationUnit1) was autogenerated by VS and as well OrganizationUnit2. I added the annotation above so that the recursivenes before mentione could work at the views.

Comment: Here is a business Example: lets say the parent unit is called IT with code=3. Then we have R&D as a child, with weighing 35. Another child Infraestructure with weighing 35 as well. Pretend these are already saved. Now we are intruducing a new one, called  Support and we are trying to save it with also a weighing 35. Either after post or before the Controler should warn the user and prevent the model from saving. All children including the new have ParentUnitCode=3.

Answer (score 0):

If `OrganizationUnit1` is the collection of all other units with the same `ParentUnit`, you can perform the check in the ViewModel by implementing `IValidatableObject`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class OrganizationUnit : IValidatableObject {
    /* properties etc... */

     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
         if (OrganizationUnit1.Sum(o => o.weighing) + this.weighing > 100.0) {
               yield return new ValidationResult(
                   "Sum of weightings would exceed 100.",
                    new[] { "weighing" });
         }
     }
}
```

Note that this assumes that the `weighing` is posted back for all units in the `OrganizationUnit1` collection (e.g. as hidden fields) so it is accessible when this check is performed by the MVC pipeline (this is done before your POST action will be hit).

If this check fails, `ModelState.IsValid` will be false in the controller.

If you have no access to the other units in the Viewmodel, you will have to fetch them from the DB in the controller and perform the check there.

Answer (score 0):

After a while and tries I came up with this solution works perfect, however I am not sure is the best practice. This is on the controller class

```
    public ActionResult Create(OrganizationUnit organizationunit)
            {
                decimal weighingsum= 0;
    foreach (var val in db.OrganizationUnit.Where(t => t.ParentUnitCode== organizationunit.ParentUnitCode))
                {                        
   weighingsum+= val.weighing ;

                }
                weighingsum+= organizationunit.weighing ;
                if (weighingsum > 100)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Weighing sum can not exceed 100 for a Parent Unit");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        db.OrganizationUnit.Add(organizationunit);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                }
    return View(organizationunit);
    }
```

should anyone comes up with a better solution, please do share I'll appreciate it.